# Performant Linq Query that gets maximum revision of rows

Tags: c#, performance, linq, entity-framework

all.

I am developing an application that is tracking the changes to an objects properties. Each time an objects properties change, I create a new row in the table with the updated property values and an incremented revision.

I have a table that has a structure like the following:

- *Id* (primary key, system generated)
- *UserFriendlyId* (generated programmatically, it is the Id the user sees in the UI, it stays the same regardless of how many revisions an object goes through)
- .... (misc properties)
- *Revision* (int, incremented when an object properties are changed)

To get the maximum revision **for each UserFriendlyId**, I do the following:

```
var latestIdAndRev = context.Rows.GroupBy(r =>  r.UserFriendlyId).Select(latest => new { UserFriendlyId = latest.Key, Revision = latest.Max(r=>r.Revision)}).ToList();
```

Then in order to get a collection of the Row objects, I do the following:

```
var latestRevs = context.Rows.Where(r => latestIdAndRev.Contains( new {UserFriendlyId=r.UserFriendlyId,  Revision=r.Revision})).ToList();
```

Even though, my table only has ~3K rows, the performance on the latestRevs statement is horrible (takes several minutes to finish, if it doesn't time out first).

Any idea on what I might do differently to get better performance retrieving the latest revision for a collection of userfriendlyids?

Comment: Its not the query that matters but the indexes on the table. Show us the DDL for the table and the indexes it has. Also, would it be possible to add a  boolean `revised` field that would be `false` for the most recent record and `true` for all the older revised ones? It makes making a permanent filtered index a lot easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To increase the performance of you query you should try to make the entire query run on the database. You have divided the query into two parts and in the first query you pull all the revisions to the client side into `latestIdAndRev`. The second query `.Where(r => latestIdAndRev.Contains( ... ))` will then translate into a SQL statement that is something like `WHERE ... IN` and then a list of all the ID's that you are looking for.

You can combine the queries into a single query where you group by `UserFriendlyId` and then for each group select the row with the highest revision simply ordering the rows by `Revision` (descending) and picking the first row:

```
latestRevs = context.Rows.GroupBy(
  r => r.UserFriendlyId,
 (key, rows) => rows.OrderByDescending(r => r.Revision).First()
).ToList();
```

This should generate pretty efficient SQL even though I have not been able to verify this myself. To further increase performance you should have a look at indexing the `UserFriendlyId` and the `Revision` columns but your results may vary. In general adding an index increases the time it takes to insert a row but may decrease the time it takes to find a row.

(General advice: Watch out for `.Where(row => clientSideCollectionOfIds.Contains(row.Id))` because all the ID's will have to be included in the query. This is not a fault of the ER mapper.)

Comment: Thank you, Martin! I tried your proposed query and it worked much, much faster. I have not indexed the two columns, yet. I would like to take a before and after shot of performance to see what improvements the indexes might accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things to look at, as you are likely ending up with serious recursion. If this is SQL Server, open profiler and start a profile on the database in question and then fire off the command. Look at what is being run, examine the execution plan, and see what is actually being run.

From this you MIGHT be able to use the index wizard to create a set of indexes that speeds things up. I say might, as the recursive nature of the query may not be easily solved.

If you want something that recurses to be wicked fast, invest in learning Window Functions. A few years back, we had a query that took up to 30 seconds reduced to milliseconds by heading that direction. NOTE: I am not stating this is your solution, just stating it is worth looking into if indexes alone do not meet your Service Level Agreements (SLAs).

Comment: The question is tagged [entity-framework], not [linq-to-sql]. I am not sure which technology your rant applies to.